# Asynchronous module loading(AMD) with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, amd

I am working on a web application and testing some things like WebSocket with Socketio. At the moment I am thinking about a solution like requierejs with Socketio. It's is working fine and I can load Javascript files and parse them with "new Function()" (security?). Is the performance better if I load the files with "normal"(Using script elements) AMD?

```
system.create.script(['rg.observable', 'rg.route', 'rg.bindings.*', 'rg.utils.*'], function() {

    var bind = function(node) {}
    return bind;

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "amd"?

Answer (score 0):

td;dr, I don't really think it would worth spending time on it.

Asking about performance, I would really say you have to try it in your production environment.

There's too many moving parts so that each might be a faster in one case. First there comes different browsers, each might be faster or slower in different places. Then socket.io has different transports depending on the browser and network support(websockets are not supported everywhere). Then comes the client network which could have high or low bandwidth or latency. Also the load on your servers and the number of your servers could affect which would be faster.

But from my experience(not much though), this is how it looks:

If your application is small enough my suggestion to you is that just compile and compress your requirejs modules into one or two file and just just serve that with regular http. In most cases it should be faster than loading socket.io dynamically since you have to wait for socket.io script to be downloaded and executed, wait for socket.io transport to be set up(handshakes and stuff), and then resolve dependencies dynamically and a waterfall effect happens right there.

But if you have a huge application which contains many modules and you wouldn't wanna to load all at the beginning(let's say something very heavy that users won't use all it's features everytime they load it), then you might think it might be worth looking into. But the difference would be only be having a one websocket connection(let's ignore other socket.io transports because they use http too) vs 2 or 3(more than this, it means you are doing something wrong!) http requests.

Technically if you are using http keep-alive, then they both should take the same time assuming you got the right setup since browsers keep the http connection alive for a minute or more, so you won't be creating new ones so it would be similar to a websocket connection. Now if you throw in SPDY, then using socket.io might even be slower because it would be just a extra overhead.

Now talking about a nice and performant way to load modules dynamically, you should watch this talk: [Malte Ubl & John Hjelmstad: A novel, efficient approach to JavaScript loading](http://youtu.be/mGENRKrdoGY)